# „Rehallo“, „wiederhallo“ oder „Hallo noch mal“: Was davon kann man auf Deutsch verwenden?

Tags: phrase

Manchmal passiert folgendes:

> Ich sehe eine Person und sage „Hallo“. Nach 2 Stunden sehe ich diese Person wieder und ich weiß nicht, was ich auf Deutsch sagen soll, außer noch mal „Hallo“. Am Ende sage ich „Ciao“. In diesem Fall denke ich immer an die wunderbaren italienischen Redewendungen „Risalve“ oder „Riciao“ oder „Ancora una volta buongiorno/buona giornata/buona serata/arrivederci/..“ oder „Nuovamente Arrivederci“ etc.

Als ich Deutsch studiert habe, habe ich meine Deutschlehrerin, eine Deutsch-Muttersprachlerin, die Rumänisch studiert hat, gefragt, ob solche Ausdrücke, wie es sie auf Italienisch gibt, auch auf Deutsch für die obengenannte Situation möglich sind oder nicht. Sie hat ein paar Minuten darüber nachgedacht und mir geantwortet:

„Vielleicht *rehallo*, warum nicht? Es klingt gut, aber ich bin nicht sicher, normalerweise sagt man nichts. Ich muss recherchieren, interessante Frage.“ (Ich glaube, das Präfix *re* stammt aus dem Französischen.)

Leider hatte ich keine sichere Antwort am Ende des Kurses, trotzdem habe ich den Ausdruck verwendet aber niemand hat mich verstanden. Deswegen habe ich ein bisschen gegoogelt und eine Seite von [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Praefixe-F/re.html) gefunden, und nun stelle ich meine Frage:

*Kann man Ausdrücke wie „rehallo“, „wiederhallo“, „hallo noch mal“ usw. auf Deutsch verwenden?*

Comment: "Rehallo" und "wiederhallo" klingen auf jeden Fall komisch.

Comment: "Hallo nochmal" ist gängig - vor allem am Telefon.

Comment: „Rehallo” und „Wiederhallo” habe ich noch nie gehört. Letzteres erinnert mich eher an „Wiederhall” und ich würde es nicht verstehen. „Hallo noch mal” klingt natürlich für mich.
Ich Internet-Chaträumen (IRC) hab es genau hierfür den Begriff „Re” allerdings zumindest vor etwa zwanzig Jahren. Ich weiß nicht, ob er irgendwo noch gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Die ersten zwei kann man mit einer Wörterbuchsuche ausschließen. Des weiteren kann man Riciao usw. in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen. Gegenüber Italienischsprachigen kannst Du einfach Riciao verwenden und Leutte, die Du häufiger siehst, und die Dir wohlgesonnen sind, kannst Du auch gut so grüßen - zur Not fragen die halt 1x nach, was das soll und Du erklärst es.

Comment: "re" gebrauche ich durchaus öfter, allerdings mit Gegenübern, die auch alle schon vor 20-10 Jahren IRC benutzt haben.

Answer (score 9):

Ein paar Sätze, die in dieser Situation passen:

- So sieht man sich wieder.
- Du schon wieder.
  *Kann leicht negativ klingen, daher nur zusammen mit einem freundlichen Lächeln verwenden.*
- Lange nicht gesehen.

Answer (score 8):

Nichts davon ist allgemein üblich. Möglicherweise gibt es kleine Freundeskreise, innerhalb derer sich das eingebürgert hat, aber selbst das halte ich für unwahrscheinlich.

Wenn man sich zwei Stunden nach dem ersten Gruß noch einmal begegnet, ist es meistens üblich, einander nur höflich zuzulächeln und kurz mit dem Kopf zu nicken. Es ist aber auch durchaus üblich, sich noch einmal zu grüßen. Das hängt sehr von den allgemeinen Gepflogenheiten innerhalb der Gruppe ab.

Aber noch einmal: Von Grüßen wie »Re-Hallo«, »Wiederhallo« oder ähnlichen habe ich noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 8):

Von den genannten Formen ist "Hallo noch mal" die einzige, die man im Deutschen verwenden kann, allerdings nicht unbedingt in der geschilderten Situation. Diese Situation klingt so, als ob es sich eher um einen flüchtigen Gruß handelt, wie zwischen Kollegen, die sonst nicht viel miteinander zu tun haben. Da würde "Hallo noch mal" m. E. schrullig wirken.

Man könnte es zum Beispiel in folgenden Situationen verwenden:

- Ich rufe jemanden an, man begrüßt sich, aber die Leitung bricht ab. Ich rufe noch einmal an, und könnte mich dann mit "(So,) hallo noch mal" melden (oder auch "Da bin ich wieder").
- Ich vereinbare mit der anderen Person einen Rückruf, damit ich zwischenzeitlich etwas in Erfahrung bringe. Ich könnte dann sagen, "Hallo noch mal, ich habe jetzt nachgesehen, ..."
- Nachdem ich mich verabschiedet habe, fällt mir ein, dass ich etwas vergessen habe — zum Beispiel, dass ich die andere Person noch etwas fragen wollte. Dann könnte ich mich mit einem "Hallo noch mal" an sie wenden. Wie angemessen das jeweils ist, hängt natürlich auch davon ab, wie vertraut wir sind. Freunden gegenüber könnte das etwas zu distanziert klingen. Zu Autoritätspersonen wiederum würde man wohl sowieso nicht "Hallo" sagen, sondern könnte sehr höflich etwa "Guten Tag, dürfte ich nochmal kurz stören?" formulieren.

Answer (score 4):

Die Ausdrücke *»rehallo«* und *»wiederhallo«* gibt es im Deutschen nicht. Begegnet man Menschen, die man grüßt, innerhalb kurzer Zeit erneut, könnte man dagegen sagen:

- »Schon sieht man sich wieder.«
- »Verdammt kleine Welt!«

Und mit launigem Unterton:

- »Angenehm; sehr erfreut.«
- »Kennen wir den? [Ich glaube: ja.]«
- »Irgendwoher kenne ich Sie. [Wenn ich [doch] bloß wüsste, woher ...]«
- »Sie kommen mir bekannt vor. Ich glaube, wir kennen uns.«

Answer (score 4):

Gängig ist ganz einfach

> Hallo nochmals!

Oder je nach gewünschtem Höflichkeitsgrad eben

> Guten Tag nochmals!

oder, südliche Regionen vorausgesetzt

> Grüßgott nochmals!

Möglich ist auch

> Hallo schon wieder!

doch birgt dies die Gefahr, dass es als etwsa unfreundlich ausgelegt wird, jedenfalls wenn es der sagt, der am Ort geblieben war und vom erneuten Besuch überrascht wird.

Answer (score 2):

Die vorangegangen Antworten sind zutreffend in dem Sinn, dass im *gesprochenen* Deutsch derartige re- oder wieder- Vorsilben bei Begrüßungen nicht vorkommen.

Eine andere Situation liegt allerdings in Chat-Räumen vor. Sofern es dort üblich ist, dass Neuankömmlinge die Anwesenden grüßen und ihrerseits gegrüßt werden, ist "re*(Gruß)*" das Normale.
Je nach Charakter des Raums und der Anwesenden kann es dabei aber auch schon mal zu humoristischen Reaktionen kommen - ein "rehi" wird gerne vorsätzlich als reh-i missverstanden und entsprechend mit "elchi" oder Ähnlichem beantwortet. (Einmal sah ich als Reaktion auf ein "rehuhu" - die Person grüßte sonst oft mit "huhu" - die Frage nach der Flügelspannweite).

Answer (score 0):

Ich kenne beim zweiten Wiedersehen nur

> Das nächste Mal gibst **du** aber einen **aus**!

; )

Answer (score 0):

Statt ein zweites Mal "Hallo" zu sagen reicht auch ein freundliches Lächeln und ggf. ein kleines Kopfnicken.